# Where does the style guide get generated?

Tags: 8, theming

I just enabled the [Zen](https://www.drupal.org/project/zen) theme, created a new sub theme and ran gulp successfully. On the Zen documentation, it says a gulp task should generate a styleguide for me, but I am not sure what the url is or how to find the generated styleguide.

> [Zen](https://www.drupal.org/project/zen) now includes a KSS-based living style guide. KSS reads comments in your Sass files and automatically generates a Style Guide that shows how your actual CSS works on your Drupal site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you run `gulp`, the style guide will be generated in

> /path/to/your/theme/styleguide/

Just open the index.html file in your browser to view the contents.